# Append player ID to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append the player-id to input field on page load?

```
    <input type="text" id="player-id" readonly /> 

    <a id="get_onesignal_token" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="getOneSignalToken()">Get OneSignal player id</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getOneSignalToken() {
        //alert("RegisterId:" + android.getOneSignalRegisteredId());
        $('#player-id').val($('#player-id').val() + android.getOneSignalRegisteredId());
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code appears to be doing what you require. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi. Alert is working but append is not

Comment: Append is working only onClick action

Comment: Where are you calling `getOneSignalToken()` from?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: <a id="get_onesignal_token" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="getOneSignalToken()">Get OneSignal player id</a>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I m using the above button. But I need to append not on click on page load

Comment: So... just call the function when the page loads? Also there is no link between the button and the function in the small snippet of code you've shown.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes exactly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You should call your method onLoad of document, like I did in body

```
<body onload="getOneSignalToken()">
 <input type="text" id="player-id" readonly /> 

    <a id="get_onesignal_token" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="getOneSignalToken()">Get OneSignal player id</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getOneSignalToken() {
        //alert("RegisterId:" + android.getOneSignalRegisteredId());
        $('#player-id').val($('#player-id').val() + android.getOneSignalRegisteredId());
      };
    </script>
</body>
```

Let me know if you have still any doubt

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function getOneSignalToken() {
     $('#player-id').val($('#player-id').val() + android.getOneSignalRegisteredId());
        })
```

This worked. Thanks.